Excel VBA - gif image stuck on excel WebBrowser control
I have a login UserForm called frmLogin.
When I click on "Login" button I connect to a database and after some checks and in case of positive response frmApplication gets shown.
Between the two form and during the connection to a database I would like to show a form (frmLaunchingApplication) with an embedded WebBrowser containing an animated gif as below:
Lauching Userform
The code I have developed works but the gif image seems to be stuck without any animation even If I'm using some DoEvents on my code.
Any suggestion?
This is how I'm managing the code on Login button of frmLogin:
frmLogin.Hide 
Load frmLaunchingApplication 
DoEvents 
frmLaunchingApplication.Show FormShowConstants.vbModeless 
DoEvents
Connection to the database
If all checks are OK then
Load frmACPTrackRequest 
frmACPTrackRequest.Show FormShowConstants.vbModeless 
Unload frmLaunchingApplication

Thanks
Getting help to solve my issue
